# what is space overhead (when referring to a c++ array)?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm reading a lecture slide in my data structures class for arrays, but there is something that sort of confused me.

The example is in an array called x, defined as follows:

1-dimensional array x = [a, b, c, d]
location(x[i]) = start + i

[image]

I'm not really understanding this, so could somebody explain this?

Comment: If this slide is attempting to explain that pointer *variables* themselves occupy memory in addition to what they point to, it is doing it in just about the most obtuse way I've seen in some time. The graphic is nearly useless, and the four-lead blocks offer up a rather unfortunate red-herring if that is the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`start` is a variable, which holds address to the array. Since a pointer in 32-bit system has 4 bytes, it will occupy these four bytes. So if you want 4-byte array, you will actually need 8 bytes of memory: 4 for the array and another 4 for pointer to the first element of this array.

Comment: "So if you want 4-byte array,  you will actually need 8 bytes of memory" - only if you specifically ask for a pointer variable to the start of the array.  Normally, you'd write [`const`] `char x[] = { a, b, c, d };` and `sizeof x` would be four bytes... there is no pointer.  There's nothing in the slide's preamble about "start" being a separate `char*`, but it's implied by the diagram and talk of 4-byte overhead.

Comment: What do you mean by "specifically ask for a pointer to the start of the array"? How would one do that?